# Need an alternative for a python for loop which iterates a certain number of files every 5 minutes and does some action

Tags: python, azure, for-loop, aws-lambda, azure-functions

My python program runs every 5 minutes on the cloud.  The program reads a certain list of files, and the files each contain a timestamp.  If the timestamp matches within the current 5 minutes, the program does a particular action.

Here is an example:

I have a directory "D:/files" with n number of files. The loop will work like this,

```
for one_file in files:
    time_in_file=one_file["time"]
    if time_in_file==within_next_five_minutes:
        do_a_particular_action
    else:
        move_to_the_next_file
```

Currently, I am using a small number of files (approximately 50), which is why it is working fine.  In the coming future, the number of files is expected to be in the hundreds or thousands, and the process will take more than 5 minutes to complete.  Is there any better way to optimize this other than iterating each file one by one?

Comment: The is the higher-level use case you are wanting to achieve? That is, _why_ do you want to read these files and do an action? If you can tell us more about the goal you are trying to achieve, we will possibly be able to provide you with a better answer or a better approach to achieving what you are trying to do. (Eg using a database or a library that already does what you want.) Feel free to edit your Question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend creating 2 different processes one for loading the files and a second one to process each file. Depending on how the files look like, you can send them as they are on the queue, or in pieces. The queue has the responsibility to connect the 2 processes and send the data in between them.

**Create 2 methods : load_files, process_file and create a process for each of them. First methods writes on the queue , second one is reading from the queue.**

The queue object should be sent as argument to each of the methods, in the args.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
    ....
    queue = mp.Queue()
    loader= mp.Process(target=load_files, args=(queue, ....))
    processor = mp.Process(target=process_file, args=(queue, ....))
    ....
    loader.start()
    processor.start()
    ....
    loader.join()
    processor.join()
```

Depending on how fast your loader vs. how fast the processor is, you can choose to wait on the second vs. on the first process (e.g. : by checking the queue size) : 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.qsize

```
qsize() # qsize() method can help. but please be aware it does now work on every 
        # operating systems.
```

Using this approach, you can start multiple processes to process files, or to put on queue. But you should find an easy way to balance in between processes that have the same responsibility, if you have a higher load than what a single process can do. For even higher loads, there are definitely frameworks that you can use. Let me know if you need suggestions for such a framework.

Cheers!